# Configuring a JDBC Resource to a Connection Pool in Glassfish

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

I have configured a **JDBC-Connection Pool** called *jdbc*, and that works fine when I ping it.

Now I need to create a **JDBC Resource**.

How do I do this? The documentation on the internet is really poor. I read somewhere you need to set the jndi name and the pool name as properties for the JDBC resource. These two values then refer to the connection pool (in my case *jdbc*)

But is it jndiName? "JNDI Name"? *JNDIName? pool name? PoolName?*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed some things up. You have to set the JNDI name and the Pool name for the JDBC Resource you want to create.

Just go to `JDBC Resources` and click `New`.

`JNDI Name` is the name you want to use for your jdbc resource (in your persistence.xml etc.)

`Pool Name` is the name of the Connection Pool you just created under `JDBC Connection Pools`. In your case it would be `jdbc` but you can only choose from existing pools in the dropdown anyway.

[image: jdbc resource]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from my scripts for creating Glassfish domains:

create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" --restype="javax.sql.XADataSource" --steadypoolsize="0" --maxpoolsize="100" --poolresize="1" --statementtimeout="60" --property "URL=connectionUrl" jdbc/Connection-Pool

create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid jdbc/Connection-Pool jdbc/Datasource

in short, you just need to create a resource that points back to the Pool you've created, then you can use the Datasource in your applications.

Comment: plus, if you look at the sample resources already there, they should point at the same connection pools, so you can see on the GUI have the fields map to each other.

Comment: so i dont really need these two jndiName/poolName fields?