# Can't start GlassFish server - The module has not been deployed

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I've just installed Netbeans 7.4 on a new computer and cloned my project (created in Netbeans 7.3) from GitHub. However when I try to run it Glassfish fails to start and I can't figure out why.

Project log:

```
In-place deployment at D:\Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CarRentalProject\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.0, deploy, null, false
D:\Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CarRentalProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1033:     The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

GlassFish log:

```
SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : danu6__pm
```

The database I'm trying to connect to is called danu6, but I don't know where the __pm suffix is coming from, and I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting persistence.xml and creating a new one seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you have no JDBC resource called `danu6`.

In the Glassfish admin GUI you have to setup a **connection pool** first, then you can add a **JDBC resource** which uses the fresh created **connection pool**. 

 [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262632/configuring-a-jdbc-resource-to-a-connection-pool-in-glassfish/20268660#20268660) explains how to setup such a **JDBC resource**.

**See also:**

- [JDBC resource name being modified by container ('_pm' being appended to it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065661/jdbc-resource-name-being-modified-by-container-pm-being-appended-to-it)
- [Java, JPA, Glassfish, Invalid resource : jdbc/__default__pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407505/java-jpa-glassfish-invalid-resource-jdbc-default-pm)
- [JNDI resource name appended with _pm . Deployment fails .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473918/jndi-resource-name-appended-with-pm-deployment-fails)

Comment: Why didn't I have to do any of that when I created the project in the first place?

Comment: You did have to...or someone preconfigured it for you.

Comment: I created a blank project in Netbeans and definitely never went to the Glassfish admin panel before. Anyway, deleting persistence.xml and creating a new one seems to have fixed the issue.